# How to prove by induction that $(n+1)^n < n^{n+1}$ for $n\ge 3$?

Tags: inequality, induction

Here is an inequality (let's call it - "$A(n)$") that has to be proved:
$$
 (n+1)^n < n^{n+1} \text{ for } n\ge3.
$$

I'll skip the first two steps of induction and move right to the induction step (step #3) in order not to waste time.

3. Assume that $n = k+1$. I get:
   $$
   (k+2)^{k+1} < (k+1)^{k+2}
   $$
   From here:
   $$
   (k+2)^k(k+2) < (k+1)^k(k+1)^2
   $$
   and that is where i'm stuck.

I've found, that the inequality $A(n)$ (by dividing it by $n^n$) can be expressed as:
$$
(1+1/n)^n < n.
$$
Here again I substitute $n = k+1$ and get:
$$
(1+1/(k+1))^{k+1} < k+1.
$$
Stuck here as well...

On the forum I've found ways to prove the inequality by Binomial theorem and other approaches, but how to prove this with math induction ? It would be great if answers included comments on every step, that is done to find the solution...

Comment: Use induction hypothesis

Comment: Got it. Thank You for the fast response.